# IPV6 Internet Conntion Only Working with VirtualBox Bridge Adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge

On an Ubuntu 16.04 host with WIN 10 VirtualBox guest, I'm using a Bridge Adapter network connection. The internet connection worked just fine until I added a wireless network extender.

That extended wireless connection is preventing the WIN 10 guest to obtain an IPV4 address (although the host works fine).

I can browse IPV6 enabled sites, such as Google and Facebook. But the majority of websites won't load.

I've tried ipconfig /release /renew /dnsflush, removing the device driver and reinstalling in the WIN 10 guest. A IPV4 connection is never established. Beyond these I'm not sure how else to resolve.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or fix this?

Edit: The host is on a wireless connection and the extender is a wi-fi extender. The extender is connected to the router over wi-fi and is broadcasting the same SSID as the wireless router.

Comment: What kind of extender? Wired or wireless uplink? The latter type have to do L2 NAT, so they might be confused by a single client MAC trying to obtain multiple IP addresses. (I'm assuming the host itself is using Wi-Fi to connect...)

Comment: Yes @grawity thanks for the questions.... I missed those details. The host is on a wireless connection and it's a wifi extender. The extender is broadcasting the same SSID as the wireless router.

Comment: Yes, but is the extender _itself_ connected to the main router over Wi-Fi or over Ethernet?

Comment: @grawity the extender is connected over wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling dual-band broadcast on the wireless router, and connecting to just the 2.4 Ghz connection, everything returned to normal. The guest machine is now using IPV4 and IPV6 without issue.